# Terrible Windows iperf performance

Tags: networking, firewall, bandwidth

I'm having a weird issue that's totally stumping me. The performance of 10G ethernet on my Windows computer is poor in the incoming direction from one computer, and exceptionally poor from another. **Why are the speeds so different between the various computers and in different directions?** And why does the firewall kill the TCP performance so badly?

There are three computer I'll discuss here:

Old Server: an Intel i7-7220X with an Asus 10G x4 ethernet adapter (over PCIe chipset port), running Unraid

New Server: a DL380p with dual 10G SFP+, running CentOS (9) Stream

Desktop: AMD Ryzen 9 5950X running Windows 10 with ...

- ... original tests had an Asus 10G ethernet adapter
- ... just replaced it with a PCIe x8 dual 10G SFP+ adapter

I have a 10G SFP+ network switch.

- Old Server <-- RF45 (20ft; cat 6) --> SFP+/RJ45 10G adapter <--> Switch
- New Server <-- SFP+ 10G cable --> Switch
- Desktop (before) <-- RJ45 (100ft; cat6) --> SFP+/RJ45 10G adapter <--> Switch
- Desktop (now) <--> SFP+/Fiber 10G adapter <-- Fiber (100ft) --> SFP+/Fiber 10G adapter <--> Switch
- 1Gb RJ45 PoE to network switch to the rest of the network

Here are the summaries of a bunch of `iperf3` runs (with the SFP+ card in the Desktop)

Between the two servers:

| Server (RX) | Client (TX) | Avg Bandwidth (Gbit/s) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Old Server | New Server | 7.1 |
| New Server | Old Server | 8.4 |

Desktop (Windows Firewall enabled):

| Server (RX) | Client (TX) | Avg Bandwidth (Gbit/s) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Desktop | New Server | **1.2** |
| Desktop | Old Server | 5.3 |
| New Server | Desktop | 6.2 |
| Old Server | Desktop | 7.4 |

Desktop (BitDefender Firewall enabled):

| Server (RX) | Client (TX) | Avg Bandwidth (Gbit/s) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Desktop | New Server | **0.24** |
| Desktop | Old Server | **1.8** |
| New Server | Desktop | 4.9 |
| Old Server | Desktop | 7.8 |

Desktop (No firewall):

| Server (RX) | Client (TX) | Avg Bandwidth (Gbit/s) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Desktop | New Server | **1.3** |
| Desktop | Old Server | 5.4 |
| New Server | Desktop | 7.8 |
| Old Server | Desktop | 7.5 |

These were the commands I used on each computer:

- New Server: `podman run -it --rm -p 5201:5201 docker.io/clearlinux/iperf -s`
- Old Server: `docker run -it --rm -p 5201:5201 docker.io/clearlinux/iperf -s`
- Desktop: `winpty ./iperf3.exe -s`

Some notes:

- The Desktop's network settings show that it has a 10G bidirectional link
- These speeds are about the same as I got with the RJ45 10Ge connection to the Desktop
- These tests are reproducible

Comment: @Ramhound Ruled out which adapters? Also, the speed between the two servers is consistent, but the Windows computer is consistently slow. Originally the Windows had RJ45 10Ge and an RJ45/SFP+ adapter in the switch. Now the Windows computer has a true SFP+ NIC with SFP+ to fiber both in it and in the switch. The hardware connection between the Windows computer and the switch has changed 100% but the speed difference remains.

Comment: @Ramhound there are a lot of SFP adapters. There have been two SFP+/RJ45 adapters, one of which still in use on the Old Server's link. On the Windoze side, I've use both another RJ45/SFP+ adapter and also a pair of SFP+/Fiber adapters - both of which produce the same result. Also, the Old Server gets high bandwidth through its RJ45 adpater to the other server, just not with Windoze.

Comment: @Ramhound At this point, I have.

Comment: I guess you are running rootless podman together with [slirp4netns](https://github.com/rootless-containers/slirp4netns). That is known to be slow. Faster options are coming. I've found (but never tried) https://passt.top/passt/about/   and [bypass4netns](https://github.com/rootless-containers/bypass4netns). Maybe not supported by iperf but sometimes socket activation could be used (I wrote https://github.com/eriksjolund/socket-activate-echo to demo socket activation with podman). Or you could run `sudo podman run --user ...` to avoid slirp4netns.

Answer (score 1):

After doing a lot more thorough/longer/parametric tests, I've found:

When receiving with firewalls turned off, this computer hits 5.45 Gb/s but can  transmit around 8 Gb/s running `iperf3` in single-stream mode.

When I use four-streams, I hit 9.5 Gb/s TX and RX reliably.

When I use four-streams and turn on the Windows Defender Firewall, I hardly notice a difference.

When I use four-streams and turn on the BitDefender Firewall, I hit 9.50 Gb/s TX but 2.3-4 Gb/s RX.

Which leads me to identifying that *both* of the following are major culprits:

- Single-stream (implying an inefficiency somewhere in Windows in how a single socket gets data to the process)
- BitDefender Firewall (holy crap)

Not 100% sure why it's different between different hosts, but c'est la vie.